# Add current date to HTML with JS / Javascript

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x

I'm making a Note app to learn Polymer and stuck with date implementation. I have this chunk of code:

```
<template>
<style>...</style>
<div class="small-note-style">
  [[data.name]]
  <div class="date-created"></div>
  <div class="small-description">
    [[data.description]]
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  /**
   * @customElement
   * @polymer
   */
  class NoteSmall extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'note-small'; }

      static get properties() {
          return {
              data: {
                  type: Object,
                  value: undefined
              }
          }
      }
  }
  window.customElements.define(NoteSmall.is, NoteSmall);

  document.getElementsByClassName("date-created").innerHTML = '<p> created on:' + new Date() +</p>;
</script>
```

What i need to get is a text saying: 'Created on Jul 23, 2018 UTC...'

Tried with last line of code and i get: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null;

Question 2: is there a way to add current date via

```
static get properties() {
          return {
              data: {
                  type: Object,
                  value: undefined
              }
          }
      }
```

Add something like date: new Date('Jul 23, 2018') to 'data' obj ?

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array. If you only need the first instance of the array you can do something like this.

```
const [dateCreated] =   document.getElementsByClassName("date-created");

dateCreated.innerHTML = `<p> created on: ${new Date()}</p>`;
```

If you have multiple elements with the same date, then just loop

```
document.getElementsByClassName("date-created").forEach(el => {
  // do something
});
```

As for your second question. More than likely.